# Modifying constraint's constant generates errors in console

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have tableView which connected to edges of superview.

```
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    tableViewBottomConstraint = tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
    tableViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
```

In some cases I need to modify tableView's bottom constraint in viewDidAppear which I do like this

```
tableViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = false
tableViewBottomConstraint?.constant = -48
tableViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
```

but this generates errors

```
2017-05-20 13:41:55.347456+0300 fooder[74115:9014905] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000096530 UITableView:0x7fe54f83b600.bottom == UIView:0x7fe54f52b050.bottom   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000097660 UITableView:0x7fe54f83b600.bottom == UIView:0x7fe54f52b050.bottom - 48   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000096530 UITableView:0x7fe54f83b600.bottom ==     UIView:0x7fe54f52b050.bottom   (active)>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try changing the constraint in  `viewDidAppear` without deactivating it.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you have duplicate `NSLayoutConstraint` for the `tableViewBottom` by looking at `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000096530` and `NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000097660`.

Make sure you check your code is not duplicating the constraint will solve the problem.